# Using the cursor in mongodb-rust sync

Tags: mongodb, rust

I took the code from the documentation, but it doesn't work.

```rust
pub fn get_countries(&self) {
  let cursor = self.countries.find(None, None);
  for doc in cursor {
    println!("{}", doc?)
  }
}
```

`mongodb::sync::Cursor<bson::Document> doesn't implement std::fmt::Display`

`mongodb::sync::Cursor<bson::Document> cannot be formatted with the default formatter`

`the ? operator can only be applied to values that implement std::ops::Try`

`the ? operator cannot be applied to type mongodb::sync::Cursor<bson::Document>`

Also the cursor.collect() does not work correctly.

> the method `collect` exists for enum `std::result::Result<mongodb::sync::Cursor<bson::Document>, mongodb::error::Error>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
>
> method cannot be called on `std::result::Result<mongodb::sync::Cursor<bson::Document>, mongodb::error::Error>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds

I tried using cursor.iter() or cursor.into_iter(), the result was the same

Full code of module

```rust
use bson::Document;
use mongodb::{
  error::Error,
  sync::{ Collection, Database},
};

pub struct Core {
  db: Database,
  countries: Collection<Document>,
}

impl Core {
  pub fn new(db: &Database) -> Core {
    Core {
      db: db.clone(),
      countries: db.collection("countries"),
    }
  }
  pub fn get_country(&self, name: &String) -> Result<Option<Document>, Error> {
    self.countries.find_one(bson::doc! { "idc": name }, None)
  }
  pub fn get_countries(&self) {
    let cursor = self.countries.find(None, None);
    for doc in cursor {
      println!("{}", doc?)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `doc` value is returning a `Cursor`, so I'm guessing that `cursor` must be rather the `Result<Cursor<T>>` type returned by the `Collection::find` method. https://docs.rs/mongodb/latest/mongodb/sync/struct.Collection.html#method.find

Shouldn't you unwrap (or handle the result with a proper match) your `self.countries.find(None, None)` result ?

```rs
pub fn get_countries(&self) {
  let cursor = self.countries.find(None, None).unwrap();
  for doc in cursor {
    println!("{}", doc?)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```rust
pub fn get_countries(&self) -> Vec<Document> {
  let cursor = self.countries.find(None, None).unwrap();
  let mut total: Vec<Document> = Vec::new();
  for doc in cursor {
    total.push(doc.unwrap());
  }
  total
}
```